# Finding a line in a file then reading next few lines in Python

Tags: python

I have a plain text file with the following data:

```
id=1
name=Scott
occupation=Truck driver
age=23

id=2
name=Dave
occupation=Waiter
age=16

id=3
name=Susan
occupation=Computer programmer
age=29
```

I'm trying to work out the best way to get to any point in the file given an `id` string, then grab the rows underneath to extract the data for use in my program. I can do something like:

```
def get_person_by_id(id):
    file = open('rooms', 'r')
    for line in file:
        if ("id=" + id) in line:
            print(id + " found")
```

But I'm not sure how I can now go through the next bunch of lines and do `line.split("=")` or similar to extract the info (put into a list or dict or whatever) that I can use my program. Any pointers?

Comment: Is all data available for each ID, or may some records have less information than others?

Comment: A lot depends on what you know about the format. Is it always 4 lines per entry? Can there be any other keys? Basically, you can call `file.readline()` several times.

Comment: Are you able/open to changing the file format a bit? You could use the csv module if you were able to. See here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html. Perhaps you could make the csv module work for this situation too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914454/python-how-to-loop-through-blocks-of-lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option would be to load the entire thing into memory, which would save you from reading the file every time:

```
with open('rooms') as f:
    chunks = f.read().split('\n\n')

people_by_id = {}

for chunk in chunks:
    data = dict(row.split('=', 1) for row in chunk.split('\n'))
    people_by_id[data['id']] = data
    del data['id']

def get_person_by_id(id):
    return people_by_id.get(id)
```

Comment: If the file is very large it may be better not to read the entire file into memory, but rather stop file processing at a specific line. Some of the other answers offer such a solution.

Answer (score 1):

How about exiting from a for loop after finding the correct line:

```
def get_person_by_id(id):
    file = open('rooms', 'r')
    for line in file:
        if ("id=" + id) in line:
            print(id + " found")
            break
    #now you can continue processing your file:
    next_line = file.readline()
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
d = dict()

with open(filename) as f:
    for line in f:
        k,v = line.split('=')
        if 'id=' in line:
            d[v] = {}
        d[d.keys()[-1]][k] = v
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all the person's attributes and values (*i.e.* id, name, occupation, age, etc..), till you find 
an empy line.

```
def get_person_by_id(id):
    person = {}
    file = open('rooms', 'r')
    for line in file:
        if found == True:
            if line.strip():
                attr, value = line.split("="):
            else:
                return person              
        elif ("id=" + id) in line:
            print(id + " found")
            found = True
            attr, value = line.split("=")
            person[attr] = value
    return person
```

Answer (score 0):

And here is an iterative solution.

```
objects = []
current_object = None
with open("info.txt", "rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip("\r\n")
        if not line:
            current_object = None
            continue
        if current_object is None:
            current_object = {}
            objects.append(current_object)
        key,_,value = line.partition('=')
        current_object[key] = value

print objects
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example of an iterative parser:

```
from itertools import takewhile
def entries(f):
    e = {}
    def read_one():
        one = {}
        for line in takewhile(lambda x: '=' in x, f):
            key, val = line.strip().split('=')
            one[key] = val
        return one
    while True:
        one = read_one() 
        if not one:
            break
        else:
            e[one.pop('id')] = one
    return e
```

Example:

```
>>> with open('data.txt') as f:
..:    print entries(f)['2']
{'age': '16', 'occupation': 'Waiter', 'name': 'Dave'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit more forgiving of empty lines within records.

```
def read_persons(it):
    person = dict()
    for l in it:
        try:
            k, v = l.strip('\n').split('=', 1)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            if k == 'id': # New record
                if person:
                    yield person
                    person = dict()
            person[k] = v
    if person:
        yield person
```